# Connect from VM XP on win 7 to win7 iis localhost

Tags: iis, windows-7, windows-xp, localhost, virtual-machine

Developing an MVC application, i now need to have test other browser versions.

Installed the VM XP on win 7. That is running good. Got IE8 installed and FF 3.6. I know IE9 has a compat mode for 8 and 7, but read some articles that these may not run exactly as their stand alone versions. I got IE8 installed on the VM XP, so now i need to connect to my IIS Win7 localhost.

IS there anyway to do this? and How?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to configure your **HOST PC's** firewall to allow the VM (and perhaps other machines) to connect on port 80.

You can then navigate to `http://hostmachinename` in the VM.

Answer (score 0):

Although my firewall was off, i was able to connect using the local machine name or ip address, as stated above by SLaks. So, if anyone has there firewall on, you may have to allow the VM to access the ports.

I did set the VMXP >> Tools >> Settings >> Networking to my Nic/ethernet card.
Not sure if this had any effect.

I also had trouble at first not getting the .NET MVC website to run. But then realized our web.config is setup to take only https. I had my website running on 2 ports, one for is for SSL. When i use the https secure port, it connected. So iguess the web app was seeing the VM  as another computer tryingto coinnect, that was not local, so it required it to connect by https.